# Displaying a json file with highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some difficulties displaying a graph with Highstock. It seems like I can't have access to the x-axis part where the graph should be displayed. I am new with Highstocks so my code could seem like a mess but my idea was the following:
First access the json file from the server. Convert it in the right format [[datestamp, value], ....]. Then display the graph.

Here is my Json file (file.json):

```
[{"date":"2013-10-04T22:31:12.000Z","value":30000},{"date":"2013-10-04T22:31:58.000Z","value":35000},{"date":"2013-10-04T22:32:05.000Z","value":60000},{"date":"2013-10-04T22:32:12.000Z","value":45000}]
```

My code is the following:

> ```
>     $(function() {
>
> chartOjb = new Object();
> var mydata = [];
> ```
>
> $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
>
> ```
>        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
>             chartOjb.name = getTimestamp(item.date);
>             chartOjb.data = item.value;
>             mydata.push({ x: chartOjb.name, y: parseFloat(chartOjb.data) });
>
>
>         }); 
>       $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
>
>           chart: {
>                 type: 'candlestick',
>                 zoomType: 'x'
>             },
>
>           navigator: {
>                 adaptToUpdatedData: false,
>                 series: {
>                     data: mydata
>                 }
>             },
>
>             scrollbar: {
>                 liveRedraw: false
>             },
>
>           xAxis: {
>                 type: 'datetime',
>                 title: 'Time',
>                 //minRange: 3600 * 1000/15 // one hour
>             },
>
>           rangeSelector : {
>               selected : 1
>           },
>
>           title : {
>
>               text : value
>           },
>
>           series : [{
>               name : 'Capacité',
>               data : data,
>
>               tooltip: {
>                   valueDecimals: 2
>               }
>           }]          });         });
>
> });
> ```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your function `getTimestamp()`? Maybe there is something wrong. 
Keep in mind that:

- x-value should be timestamp,
- when using a lot of objects `{ x: x, y: y }`, set [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold)

Comment: Here is my code for getTimestamp():     function getTimestamp(str) {
  var d = str.match(/\d+/g); 
  return +new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5]); 
}

Comment: `data : data,` <- shouldn't be ther `data: mydata,` ?